# Docker is not saving output file from Scrapy spider

Tags: python, docker, scrapy, dockerfile

I have a problem with Scrapy inside a Docker. In a docker my spider is not saving output file with results.

This is script that I am running to start spider:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from CARS_PL_source_1 import CARSPLsource1Spider

if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
    process.crawl(CARSPLsource1Spider)
    process.start()
```

Inside my pipeline I have this code to save output:

```
from scrapy.exporters import JsonItemExporter


class JsonPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.file = open("file.json", 'wb', buffering=0)
        self.exporter = JsonItemExporter(self.file, encoding='utf-8', ensure_ascii=False)
        self.exporter.start_exporting()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.exporter.export_item(item)
        return item

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.exporter.finish_exporting()
        self.file.close()
```

And my docker file looks like this:

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 
COPY car_prices_tool_scrapy/requirements.txt ./
 
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY car_prices_tool_scrapy .
 
CMD [ "python", "spiders/run_CARS_PL_source_1.py" ]
```

Without docker, spider is saving this file.json. And while running on docker I can see that spider is working and getting results in logs but I don't get anywhere my file.

When I do `docker diff` I get many temp files, pycache files etc. but this file.json is nowhere to be seen.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you running your container ? The exact `docker run ...` command. If you do not mount a local volume to the container, the `file.json` is lost after the exit of the container.

Comment: This time I ran it with this command:
`docker run -d   --name devtest   -v myvol2:/app   source_1` but after I did `docker diff` it still listed only those pycache and other temp files without json.

Comment: Your output json is probably written inside the docker container. From dockerfile the workdir is /usr/src/app which is not mounted in your docker run command.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am learing docker "on the fly" I would say. Right now I ran my script in entire different way. I entered `docker start devtest` then `docker exec -it devtest bash` and then `python run_CARS_PL_source_1.py`. I was able to see all my files from scrapy, my requirements.txt file etc. But still after I ran the script I still cannot find json. I must have made some error?